# Show multiple relationship records in single view

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have an entity (asset) that has an N:1 relationship with Parent Account and Organisation (both the same Account entities)

In the account entity, I can see either assets linked to it via parent account, or assets linked to it via organisation account, but not both (as far as I can work out).

I can't change the schema to have parent accounts as one entity and organisation accounts as another entity.

Is it possible to show both relationships in one sub-grid, or am I purely limited to having two separate sub-grids on the account entity?

Comment: So one Asset has one Account and one Organization and they are different Lookups? And you need to show in the account the assets with an Account and an Organization?

Comment: @Sxntk Yeah, with the default 1:N relationships, the view allows you to pick either Asset(Parent) or Asset(Organization) and I'm wanting it to effectively be Asset(Both)

Comment: The Account has an organization too?

Comment: @Sxntk Accounts are both Organisations and Parents (i.e. there are two N:1 relationships between Asset and Account, one called Parent and one called Organisation)

Comment: Are you able to make that view in Advance Find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this out-of-the-box since a sub-grid only supports a single 1:N relationship. You could do this by creating custom FetchXml and modifying the sub-grid via JavaScript since the query is possibly via FetchXml and can be built in Advanced Find.

Follow this [blog article](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paul-nieuwelaars-blog/2013/01/24/filter-sub-grid-dynamics-crm-2011-rollup-12-(polaris)) for information on setting the FetchXML of a sub-grid.

You'll need an on load function on your form similar to this:

```
function filterSubGrid() {
var accountsGrid = document.getElementById("accounts"); //grid to filter
if (accountsGrid == null) { //make sure the grid has loaded
    setTimeout(function () {
        filterSubGrid();
    }, 2000); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again when it has
    return;
}

var contactValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("primarycontactid").getValue(); //field to filter by

var contactId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"; //if filter field is null display nothing
if (contactValue != null) {
    var contactId = contactValue[0].id;
}

//fetch xml code which will retrieve all the accounts related to the contact
var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
    "  <entity name='account'>" +
    "    <attribute name='name' />" +
    "    <attribute name='address1_city' />" +
    "    <attribute name='primarycontactid' />" +
    "    <attribute name='telephone1' />" +
    "    <attribute name='accountid' />" +
    "    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />" +
    "    <filter type='and'>" +
    "      <condition attribute='primarycontactid' operator='eq' uitype='contact' value='" + contactId + "' />" +
    "    </filter>" +
    "    <link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='primarycontactid' visible='false' link-type='outer' alias='accountprimarycontactidcontactcontactid'>" +
    "      <attribute name='emailaddress1' />" +
    "    </link-entity>" +
    "  </entity>" +
    "</fetch>";

accountsGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchXml); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid
accountsGrid.control.refresh(); //refresh the sub grid using the new fetch xml
}
```

Except you'll need FetchXML similar to this:

```
var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
"  <entity name='new_asset'>" +
"    <attribute name='new_assetid' />" +
"    <attribute name='new_name' />" +
"    <attribute name='createdon' />" +
"    <order attribute='new_name' descending='false' />" +
"    <filter type='or'>" +
"      <condition attribute='new_organizationaccount' operator='eq' value='" + accountId + "' />" +
"      <condition attribute='new_parentaccount' operator='eq'value='" + accountId + "' />" +
"    </filter>" +
"  </entity>" +
"</fetch>";
```

The Advanced Find to get the FetchXML query is:

[image]